# Change RDS Availability Zone for reader

Tags: amazon-web-services

We already have a RDS cluster that has Writer in eu-west-1a and Reader in eu-west-1c.
I want to put the reader in the same AZ as the writer. We also have instances that are deployed in eu-west-1a.
Due to cost reasons, we need to change the reader AZ, but unfortunately I cannot see an option in AWS Console that allows you to do that.
Is there another solution for accomplishing this please?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to delete the reader and create a new reader in the desired AZ. You can't move existing resources from one AZ to another.

Answer (score 0):

**This is only a suggestion.**

As you mentioned that due to cost reasons you want to have a reader in the same AZ, in Aurora, you only pay for the storage used. And if it all you have a reader like in your case then you can perform a manual failover and have a replica of the reader in your desired AZ as the new reader.

Comment: The question appears to be about an Aurora cluster.  Other (non-Aurora) RDS offerings don't use the terms "writer" and "reader."